# Parsing variable from variables in search results

Tags: php, parsing, expressionengine

For creating search results I've got a channel field where the path to the page is stored (eg. /products/bikes).
Each entry has it's own path.

Because there are different channels, every channel has it's uniquely named channel field.
For the channel "products" it's: `{products_search_path_nl}`.

Within the results page `{exp:search:search_results}` the field is dynamically created like this: `{channel_short_name}_search_path_{language}` which is displayed as `products_search_path_nl`.

**The issue** is that it does not get parsed. After looking at EE's parse order I've tried:

- using it as a snippet
- assigning it to a PHP variable and outputting it later on
- changing PHP parsing stage (input / output)
- embedding it using a template `{embed="search/uri_embed"}`
- embedding it using a template and a template variable `{embed="search/uri_embed" passed_var="{channel_short_name}"}`
- using it within a simple conditional statement `{if "1" == "1"}`

Thanks for reading! Any help would be appriciated!

Comment: I think using an embed would be your best chance of success. What happens specifically with the embed code you posted? Can you see the variable inside your embed template?

Comment: The field name gets returned as `{products_search_path_nl}` but does not get parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Low's](http://gotolow.com/) suggestion I used a loop, since this seems impossible to solve in a propper manner.

```
    {if "{channel_short_name}" == "news"}
        {if "{news_search_path_{language}}" != ""}
            <h3><a href="{base_url}{news_search_path_{language}}{url_title}">{title} </a></h3>
            {excerpt}
        {/if}

    {if:elseif "{channel_short_name}" == "products"}    
        {if "{products_search_path_{language}}" != ""}
            <h3><a href="{base_url}{products_search_path_{language}}{url_title}">{title} </a> </h3>
            {excerpt}
        {/if}

     // ....... and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `{channel_short_name}` is parsed at the same time as all of your custom fields, as they exist in the same loop. The reason that `{language}` parses is that (I'm assuming) it's an early-parsed global variable, dynamically set by a multi-language module, or via your config setup.

And embed would work, but is hugely expensive, as you'd have to pass both the `{channel_short_name}` and `{entry_id}`, then run a whole Channel Entries loop for each result (e.g., `{exp:channel:entries channel="{embed:channel_short_name}" entry_id="{embed:entry_id}" limit="1" disable="member_data|pagination|categories"}{{embed:channel_short_name}_search_path_{language}}{/exp:channel:entries}`).

A preferred way to deal with search results from multiple channels *and* multi-language is to use a multi-language solution that dynamically alters your site path (so all `{path=""}` and `{permalink="}` variables return the proper URL for the current language), and then use the Search Results Path setting for each channel in the control panel (under **Admin → Channel Administration → Channels → Edit → Path Settings**). This will let you use the `{auto_path}` and/or `{id_auto_path}` variables in your search results.

Hope that helps?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond Derek! Adding another `{exp:channel:entries}` would be expensive indeed but it might work. As for the multi-lingual part, I can't use path variables because each entry in the channel has it's own unique path based on the assigned category and subcategory. This is also being translated.